# c++ copying elements into map

Tags: c++, dictionary, copy

I have a map of size 10 and I want to update the values of the entries with the same key values. What is the fastest way of copying into the map? Normally, I am doing the following.

```
mymap[key] = value;
```

Comment: No two keys are the same in a map.

Comment: Yes the key values (i.e. ten different keys) will stay same but the values will change.

Comment: I think that's as fast as it gets. But since your map is so small it's might actually be faster not to use a map at all, just a vector of key value pairs might be better.

Comment: Do you mean using two seperate vectors for keys and values?

Comment: @AvbAvb Or one vector of pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Using the subscript operator will search for the key and return a reference to the corresponding value. If the key does not exist in the map, a new element is inserted copying the key and default constructing the value. You can safe the use of the default constructor and instead `insert()` the key/value pairs:

```
map.insert(std::make_pair(key, value));
```

If there may be duplicates you probably want to capture the result and update the value if the object wasn't inserted.

Note that for 10 elements using a `std::vector<std::pair<Key, Value>>` with a linear search is probably faster.